# Access to class atributes in jstl without the name of the atribute

Tags: jsp, jstl

In my current spring project, I want generate the json file used by my views with this code, using json-taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
    <json:array name="item" var="item" items="${lista}">
          <json:object>
            <c:forEach var="attr" items="${atributo}">
                <json:property name="${attr}" value="${item}"/>
            </c:forEach>
          </json:object>
    </json:array>
</json:object>
```

where:

**lista** -> list of all entities of one kind stored in the database.

**atributo** -> list of all atributes from the entity

Anyone can tell me if it's possible have access to the class atributes in the expression `value="${item}` if i only have the variable `attr`?

I have tried this: `${item}.${attr}` and `${item.attr}`  without success.

Comment: Please share what type of all variables here? what it contains and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear to me but it might help you to understand about EL.

`EL` relies on the [JavaBeans specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) when it comes to accessing properties. In JSP, the following expression

```
${user.name}
```

does basically the same as the following in "raw" scriptlet code (the below example is for simplicity, in reality the reflection API is used to obtain the methods and invoke them):

```
<%
  User user = (User) pageContext.findAttribute("user");
  if (user != null) {
    String name = user.getName();
    if (name != null) {
      out.print(name);
    }
  }
%>
```

---

#### Brace notation

You can use the so-called brace notation [] to access properties by a dynamic name, to access map values by a key containing periods, to use names/keys which are by itself reserved literals in Java and to access array or list items by index.

```
${sessionScope[dynamicName]}
${someMap[dynamicKey]}
${someMap['key.with.periods']}
${some['class'].simpleName}
${someList[0].name}
${someArray[0].name}
```

The above does essentially the same as

```
session.getAttribute(dynamicName);
someMap.get(dynamicKey);
someMap.get("key.with.periods");
some.getClass().getSimpleName();
someList.get(0).getName();
someArray[0].getName();
```

[Read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Comment: What I want it's something similar to `${sessionScope[dynamicName]}` but instead of `session`, I need to use the class referred by `item`. is it possible?